# How can have Both MVC and Razor page in the same Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I have an ASP.NET Core application with Razor pages and I want take advantages of MVC into it.

I added

- Controllers folder to it with Views
- and also `services.AddMvc()` to startup
- and another endpoint to it.

I did run the project and tested if

- the simple view is returned
- and if the added controller and action after the default address works

But it did not work and returned

> "This localhost page can’t be found".

Would you please help me how I config my app?

Comment: I assume you're using visual studio, when you create a new project, you can select MVC as the project type and VS will do a lot of stuff for you, like create a HomeController with corresponding view! See this image where I am creating a new project and selecting MVC

https://imgur.com/a/65S7J3x

Comment: yes you are right . I test it now

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-6.0 via `.AddRazorPages()` `.AddControllersWithViews()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to add MVC to a Razor Page project:

### Add services to startup.cs

First you need to add `services.AddControllers();` to `ConfigureServices` and configure mvc routing in startup.cs:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddControllers();
    ...
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. 
// Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

### Add folders

Second you need to add two folders with these names

- `Controllers`
- `Views`.

Then copy

- `Pages/Shared` folder which contains  `_Layout.cshtml`
- and `_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml`

to `Views` folder.

And copy

- `Pages/_ViewImports.cshtml` to `Views/_ViewImports.cshtml`,
- `Pages/_ViewStarts.cshtml`  to `Views/_ViewStarts.cshtml`.

Here is a project structure:

[image: MVC and Razor folder structure]

Comment: I have one more question If you answer me I'll be grateful. I'll do through your guide and now I have both I want to start my project and I want the Index in view open as the first page. but now  the Index.csHtml  in page folder  come the first .

Comment: You can try to use `@page "RazorPage/Index"` in `Pages/Index`,so that `Views/Index` will primer than `Pages/Index`.Also,if you want to go to `Pages/Index`,you need to use `RazorPage/Index`.

Comment: Ok I get it tanks