# View is not found when a Web App is deployed with Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-webapps

I just migrated my Asp.Net MVC web application from .Net 2.2 to 8.0. I built and deployed the application as a Web App on Azure DevOps. When I tried to run the application in a browser, I get HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error.

I tried to diagnose using Application Insights, and found an exception:

> The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
>
> /Views/Home/Index.cshtml
> /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
> /Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml

I don't understand what could cause this, as the file is present in my project, and it runs successfully on my local computer from Visual Studio.

ADDED:

My application uses Startup.cs.

Before migration, it has the following code:

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

It was replaced with this:

```
        app.UseRouting();
        ...
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
```

And here is my Azure pipeline:

```
variables:
- name: BuildParameters.RestoreBuildProjects
  value: '**/*.csproj'
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - refs/heads/master
name: $(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)
jobs:
- job: Job_1
  displayName: Agent job 1
  pool:
    vmImage: windows-latest
  steps:
  - checkout: self
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: Use .NET Core sdk 8.0.x
    inputs:
      version: 8.0.x
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Restore
    inputs:
      command: restore
      projects: $(BuildParameters.RestoreBuildProjects)
      feedRestore: a1dd11ff-23bd-23dd-9782-e9876d2569db
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Build
    inputs:
      projects: $(BuildParameters.RestoreBuildProjects)
      arguments: --configuration $(BuildConfiguration)
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: Publish
    inputs:
      command: publish
      publishWebProjects: True
      projects: $(BuildParameters.RestoreBuildProjects)
      arguments: --configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output 
$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
      zipAfterPublish: True
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    displayName: Publish Artifact
    condition: succeededOrFailed()
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)
      TargetPath:   '\\my\share\$(Build.DefinitionName)\$(Build.BuildNumber)'
```

And here is my folder structure:

[image]

ADDED:

I downloaded the artifacts and copied them into the bin/Debug/net8.0 folder on my computer, and then ran from Visual Studio. The application worked as expected.
Then I tried to run it without Visual Studio, from the executable directly. This time it got me the same error, as on Azure:

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
  Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor[3]
  The view 'Index' was not found. Searched locations: /Views/Home/Index.cshtml, /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml, /Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
  An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
  System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
  /Views/Home/Index.cshtml
  /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
  /Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable`1 originalLocations)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ActionContext context, ViewResult result)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewResult.ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>g__Logged|22_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, IActionResult result)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.<Invoke>g__Awaited|10_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewResultExecutor[3]
  The view 'Error' was not found. Searched locations: /Views/Home/Error.cshtml, /Views/Shared/Error.cshtml, /Pages/Shared/Error.cshtml
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[3]
  An exception was thrown attempting to execute the error handler.
  System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Error' was not found. The following locations were searched:
  /Views/Home/Error.cshtml
  /Views/Shared/Error.cshtml
  /Pages/Shared/Error.cshtml
```

Comment: You're going to need to provide more details regarding your implementation. What changes did you make to your `Program.cs` when migrating from .Net 2.2 to 8.0? What does your WebApp configuration look like? What do your `CI/CD` pipelines look like? Without some more information it's nearly impossible to help.

Comment: @akseli Added the information to my question.

Comment: Where are your views located? Did you try moving them to the directory it is looking in? AspNetCore takes an approach of convention over configuration. For example, it's looking for the `Views` in the folders it mentioned in your project by convention but can be configured to look elsewhere. You may need to share a screen shot of your solution folder structure.

Comment: @AdamVincent That particular view is located right where it was looked for: /Views/Home/Index.cshtml. I will add the screenshot to my question.

Comment: I see. Generally, I think your upgrade is in a bad state.  I'm afraid if you focus on this single problem, once it's solved you may run into 10 more problems. I would suggest a holistic approach, and follow the upgrade paths outlined here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio  You'll need to follow along with multiple upgrade guides, like 2.2 to 3.0, then 3.0 to 3.1, then 3.1 to 6.0, then 6.0 to 7.0, then 7.0 to 8.0. Or you could try the cowboy method and scaffold a new .net 8 app and move your stuff into the new project.

Comment: you could also give the .NET Upgrade Assistant tool a try, I haven't had great success with it except for smaller applications though.

Comment: @AdamVincent that is what I used

Comment: Oh! You have MVC, but in your start up you are telling the app to use Razor Pages.  Razor Pages are part of the AspNetCore platform, but are seperate from MVC. Remove the `endpoints.MapRazorPages()` line, and leave the rest of `MapControllerRoute` the same.  You'll also need to register the middleware in your IServiceCollection, so above the configuration you should have something like `app.AddControllersWithViews()` or `builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()` depending on the style of the template you used.

Comment: @AdamVincent MapRazorPages is needed, as razor pages are used for login (Identity). And I have services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

Comment: @AdamVincent And how come it runs locally without problems?!!

Comment: When we register services with the DI container, order does not matter.  However, when we use those services in the middleware pipeline, order does matter.  Try moving `endpoints.MapRazorPages()` above `endpoints.MapControllerRoute(...) { ... }` Take a look at this; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70104933/how-can-have-both-mvc-and-razor-page-in-the-same-project

Comment: I understand the frustration of the "It works on my machine".  I don't know, and sometimes I find it's not worth solving the problem of getting it to work somewhere else, it's digging down to the root of the problem.

Comment: @AdamVincent Unfortunately, changing order did not help.

Comment: You mentioned that it runs successfully on your local machine from Visual Studio. Perhaps you could try downloading the Build Artifacts from the pipeline and deploy it locally to see if it runs successfully. Then, try deploying the locally compiled content to Azure Web App to see if it runs successfully. This may help narrow down the problem.

Comment: You can also enable the variable “[system. debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemdebug)”(set the value to “true”) in your pipeline , then trigger a new pipeline and check the detailed logs to find the difference between the local and Azure devops environme

Comment: @MiaoTian-MSFT Please see my last addition to the question.

Comment: Hi @DavidShochet, could you please check these similar questions: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37529040/how-do-i-solve-a-view-not-found-exception-in-asp-net-core-mvc-project) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54820782/self-hosted-asp-net-core-2-2-app-the-view-index-was-not-found-the-following).

Comment: @MiaoTian-MSFT Still no luck :(

Comment: Hi David, could you kindly [check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71108043/7687666), I have reproduce the issue in my test environment, seems the issue is expect behavior when run the executable file.

Comment: @JasonPan Thank you for this link. I added 

 <ItemGroup>
  <ViewFiles Include="$(ProjectDir)\Views\**\*.cshtml" />
 </ItemGroup>

 <Target Name="CopyViewFilesAfterPublish" AfterTargets="Publish">
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(ViewFiles)"
      DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)\Views\%(RecursiveDir)"
    />
 </Target>

to my project, and after that I was able to open the Home page. But now I cannot open Login, as it gives me "No webpage was found for the web address: https://mvpadminqa.laticrete.com/Identity/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FContractors
HTTP ERROR 404".

Comment: Hello @DavidShochet, the workaround I shared just include the pages under the Views folder, I will test it next Monday and reply you soon, thanks for your patient.

Comment: @JasonPan That worked after I included the same way my pages under Identity area! Please make your comment an answer, and I will mark it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template project we create will include all the view pages by default when you publish it.

In addition, from the comparison in the image below, we can see that from `.NET Core 2.0+` and `.NET 8` release files, `.NET 8` has removed the `projectname. Views.dll`. That's why we forced the Views folder to be included during the publishing process when we first troubleshoot.

[image]

**Workaround**

Using below settings in your `.csproj`, it can fix the issue.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ViewFiles Include="$(ProjectDir)\Views\**\*.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <Target Name="CopyViewFilesAfterPublish" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(ViewFiles)"
      DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)\Views\%(RecursiveDir)"
    />
  </Target>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ViewFiles Include="$(ProjectDir)\Areas\**\*.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <Target Name="CopyViewFilesAfterPublish" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(ViewFiles)"
      DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)\Areas\%(RecursiveDir)"
    />
  </Target>
```

**Soultion**

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Views\**">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

*For more details, you can check below 2 threads.*

This solution will keep your publishing files clean and won't generate redundant Views and Areas folders, but you may need to [learn MSBuild-related documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-8.0#include-files).

[1. Can't find my repo files after deploying to Azure App Service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69849401/7687666)

[2. How to add a folder and its contents with build action content in to uwp project?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/496984/how-to-add-a-folder-and-its-contents-with-build-ac)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before, but with GitHub action, the views and pages that caused this issue were initially copied and pasted from other views or pages and then edited.

I solved it by going to my .csproj file. IThere, you can find that these specific pages are somehow excluded.

Just delete the lines that exclude/remove these pages, and you should be good to go